# Public variable working in Inspector, but not being displayed in the Scene or Game windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have one countdown script. Once its timer (3 seconds) reaches zero, gameplay starts.
I wanted to make it so that the text will change colour during countdown (i.e. 3 - red, 2 - yellow, 1 - green).

This was rather easy to achieve, but I wasn't entirely happy with using `countdown.color = Color.green;` and wanted more flexibility (i.e. having a colour picker in the Editor).

This is the code that works:

```
Text countdown;

void OnEnable()
{
    countdown = GetComponent<Text>();
    countdown.text = "3";
    StartCoroutine("Countdown");
}

IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    int count = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        countdown.text = (count - i).ToString();
        if ((count - i) == 3)
        {
            countdown.color = Color.red;
        }
        if ((count - i) == 2)
        {
            countdown.color = Color.yellow;
        }
        if ((count - i) == 1)
        {
            countdown.color = Color.green;
        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);            
    }
    StartRound();        
}
```

And this is the one that's giving me headaches:

```
public Color color3;
public Color color2;
public Color color1;

Text countdown;

void OnEnable()
{
    countdown = GetComponent<Text>();
    countdown.text = "3";
    StartCoroutine("Countdown");
}

IEnumerator Countdown()
{
    int count = 3;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        countdown.text = (count - i).ToString();
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        if ((count - i) == 3)
        {
            countdown.color = color3;                
        }

        if ((count - i) == 2)
        {
            countdown.color = color2;                
        }

        if ((count - i) == 1)
        {
            countdown.color = color1;                
        }        
    }
    StartRound();        
}
```

The 2nd script works, but only up to a point:
- the 3 colours show up in the Inspector, and I can open the colour picker and select my desired colours;
- once I click Play though, the text doesn't show up at all (the countdown still works and gameplay starts normally after those 3 seconds), as if alpha is set to 0;
- during the countdown I can see the default colour picker (the one in the Text (Script) component) cycling through my 3 colours in the Inspector, yet I'm getting nothing in my Scene or Game view.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any reason for shifting your `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);` up before the `if` blocks? Beyond that, I don't see anything immediately obvious in terms of changes. If moving the `yield return WaitForSeconds` back down to the end of the loop doesn't fix it, then my best guess is some oversight in how you have these scripts assigned or used in the Unity inspector or some other external factor that we can't see here.

EDIT: Possible dumb question: are you double-sure that the colours you have assigned in the inspector don't have a 0 value for their alpha (that is, transparent?)

Comment: No specific reason, I was just trying things out and forgot to make it consistent in between my 2 attempts. It doesn't seem to affect things otherwise. And not a dumb question at all. Turns out you were right, alpha was set to 0 once the script compiled, but I missed it completely. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the text doesn't show up at all ... as if alpha is set to 0

Your  alpha is very likely set to 0; your code looks fine and if the first script works, then replacing it with the second script should work with correctly configured colors (hence my assumption).  If you take a look at this screenshot of the color picker, you'll notice that the color shows up in the inspector and in the color wheel but the A value (below R, G, and B) is 0.

[image: Color Picker in Inspector with 0 alpha but color still shows]

You have to manually set it to max (or whatever non-0 value you'd like) and that will be represented in the inspector by a white bar filling up below the representation of the color.  Notice in this next screenshot, I've got it set to about half so there's half of a white bar below the color in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: Yep, as mentioned in my other comment, once the script compiled, alpha was set to 0 and I've completely missed it. This is the first time I see it going straight to 0, usually it's at 255. Thank you for your answer.